# Authentication process for mobile application with MFA enabled Sharepoint-online account

Tags: c#, xamarin, sharepoint, xamarin.forms, sharepoint-online

I am trying to authenticate with SharePoint from mobile application with MFA enabled account.

I can authenticate with SharePoint if the account is not MFA enabled.

When I enable MFA for that account SharePoint Return following error:

*"Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access".*

Yes, I can use app password to by-pass MFA process. For end-user point-of-view App-Password is too complicate to generate and remember.

Without MFA I start the authentication by senting request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf".

If the account is MFA enabled, what is the address to start authentication?
And what is the process require to pass SharePoint MFA authentication?

Comment: Have you tried using the ADAL libraries?

Comment: Yes the problem with ADAL is that I have to log in every time when I relaunch the application. And I need to register app for each tenant? Can we save username and password locally for ADAL?